# How to align only one line in file to the left side with sed or perl one liner

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl

This will delete all spaces and tabs at the beginning of every line:

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*//' file
```

but lets say we want to align only the parameter `queued.max.requests=1000` from file

- Example input:

  ```
      log.flush.interval.messages=20000
      queued.max.requests = 1000
      producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=100
  ```
- Desired output:

  ```
       log.flush.interval.messages=20000
  queued.max.requests=1000
       producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=100
  ```

How we can fit the `sed 's/^[ \t]*//'` for this case? Also, I want sed/perl to delete the spaces between the parameter to "`=`" and from "`=`" to the value in the process.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller thank you so much for the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
sed '/queued\.max\.requests/s/[\t ]\{1,\}//g' file
```

or

```
sed -r '/queued\.max\.requests/s/[\t ]+//g' file
```

This will remove all space (from the beginning of the line, as well as that surrounding the `=`) from only the line containing `queued.max.requests`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/^[[:space:]]*\(queued\.max\.requests\)/\1/; s/ *= */=/' file
    log.flush.interval.messages=20000
queued.max.requests=1000
    producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=100
```